# Авто-определение кодировки файла, при открытии \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Работаю с двумя форматами, кодировок, текста: **ANSI и UTF8**. Проблема в том что - нужно постоянно, в ручную, определять кодировку текста ANSI или UTF8.

**Я делаю так:** В программе прописываю **CP_UTF8**, то есть при условии что файл находится в UTF8 кодировке он будет обработан.

**Но как решить вопрос:** При открытии файла **через OpenDialog1** - **автоматически**, определяется **кодировка** текстового файла и текстовый файл открывается в этой кодировке - ANSI, UTF8.

Мой код (Я понимаю что это нелепо и не профессионально сделано):

```
// Если выбран чекбокс1 то тогда открыть файл в кодировке UTF8
if CheckBox1.Checked then
  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(f1, OpenDialog1.FileName, CP_UTF8);
Reset(f1);

// Открываем файл для записи
AssignFile(f2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\save.txt', CP_UTF8);
Rewrite(f1);

// Если выбран чекбокс2 то тогда открыть файл в кодировке ANSI
if CheckBox2.Checked then
  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(f1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
Reset(f1);

// Открываем файл для записи
AssignFile(f2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\save.txt');
Rewrite(f1);
```

Comment: В случае использования AssignFile скорее всего никак. Для однозначного определения кодировки в файл должен записаться BOM (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов ). Следует учитывать, что для ANSI кодировки BOM нет физически

Comment: @kami, То есть выходя из этой ситуации, в моем случае, использовать код, что в вопросе - единственный выход ?

Comment: Ничего не понял из вашего комментария :) Выходом будет (например) использование TStringList с явным указанием кодировки или TFile с явным указанием кодировки. Если же файлы формируются не вами (т.е. вы не можете повлиять на наличие / отсутствие BOM), то остается только гадать.

Comment: контент файла то какой то определенный? можно бинарно считать первую строку и посмотреть  какие там байты и определить. может ли это быть ANSI, входят ли они в диапазоны символов?

Comment: @teran, Контент файла - отчеты по работе в виде .txt.

Comment: @Татьяна, на самом деле вас слегка ввели в заблуждение, есть способ определять кодировку любого файла даже без наличия в нем BOM, но это скорее похоже на гадание чем на точное определение, если вам интересно - почитайте про **частотный анализ**.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Обязательно ознакомлюсь, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть довольно старая библиотека для авто-определения кодировки: [Charset Detector](http://chsdet.sourceforge.net/). Умеет определять Win1251, UTF-8, UTF-16 и прочие популярные.

Распространяется она как в виде сорцов, так и в виде dll с файлом интерфейса для использования в Delphi. Единственное, что библиотека писалась давно (ещё до юникодных версий Delphi) и поэтому для использования в новых версия Delphi нужна небольшая правка в интерфейсе `chsd_dll_intf.pas` - заменить все типы `pChar` на `pAnsiChar`.

Пример использования:

```
uses
  Windows,      
  SysUtils,
  chsd_dll_intf;

function BytesToText(const ABytes: TBytes): WideString;
var
  P: Pointer;
  VLen: Integer;
  VOutLen: Integer;
  VInfo: rCharsetInfo;
begin
  Result := '';

  VLen := Length(ABytes);
  if VLen <= 0 then begin
    Exit;
  end;    
  P := @ABytes[0];

  csd_Reset;
  csd_HandleData(P, VLen);    
  if not csd_Done then begin
    csd_DataEnd;
  end;    
  VInfo := csd_GetDetectedCharset();

  if (VInfo.CodePage > 0) and Windows.IsValidCodePage(VInfo.CodePage) then begin
    VOutLen := MultiByteToWideChar(VInfo.CodePage, 0, P, VLen, nil, 0);
    SetLength(Result, VOutLen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(VInfo.CodePage, 0, P, VLen, PWideChar(Result), VOutLen);
  end else begin
    raise Exception.Create('CodePage detect failed');
  end;
end;
```

Вызывать примерно так (рядом с exe должна лежать chsdet.dll):

```
uses
  IOUtils;
...
var
  VText: string;
begin
  VText := BytesToText(TFile.ReadAllBytes('test_ansi_1251.txt'));
```

В моих небольших тестах библиотека успешно справилась с определением UTF-8 без BOM и Windows-1251.

Comment: Вот это то что нужно, только все сделала под свой код. Могу сказать она и с большими текстовыми файлами справляется. Выручили Вы - меня, прекрасно работает...

Answer (score 2):

В Windows есть готовые функции для этого. [Блокнот использует IsTextUnicode](https://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2009/03/blog-post_26.html), Internet Explorer использует MLang.

Например, если использовать ComboBox с содержимым вида:

- Auto
- ANSI
- UTF-8
- UTF-16

То можно использовать такой код:

```
procedure TForm1.btOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  Lines: TStringList;
begin
  if not OpenDialog.Execute then
    Exit;

  // Определили кодировку
  case cbEncoding.ItemIndex of
    1: Encoding := TEncoding.ANSI;
    2: Encoding := TEncoding.UTF8;
    3: Encoding := TEncoding.Unicode;
  else
       Encoding := DetectEncoding(OpenDialog.FileName);
  end;

  // Загрузили файл в Memo
  try
    Lines := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName, Encoding);
      mmContent.Lines.Assign(Lines);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Lines);
    end;
  finally
    if not TEncoding.IsStandardEncoding(Encoding) then
      FreeAndNil(Encoding);
  end;
end;
```

Где `DetectEncoding` - это наша функция. Например, если мы хотим поведение "как у Блокнота", то используем такой код:

```
function DetectEncoding(const AFileName: String): TEncoding;
const
  MaxBufferSize = 256;
var
  Buffer: RawByteString;
  Stream: TStream;
  Mask: Integer;
  Len: Int64;
begin
  // Загрузили начало файла в буфер Buffer для анализа
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Len := Stream.Size;
    if Len > MaxBufferSize then
      SetLength(Buffer, MaxBufferSize)
    else
      SetLength(Buffer, Len);

    Stream.Position := 0;
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Buffer)^, Length(Buffer));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Stream);
  end;

  // Явная проверка на UTF-8 с BOM, 
  // т.к. IsTextUnicode на UTF-8 не проверяет
  if Copy(Buffer, 1, 3) = #$EF#$BB#$BF then
  begin
    Result := TEncoding.UTF8;
    Exit;
  end;

  // Вызываем анализ "как в Блокноте"
  // Это сможет отличить только UTF-16 от ANSI
  Mask :=
    IS_TEXT_UNICODE_UNICODE_MASK or
    IS_TEXT_UNICODE_REVERSE_MASK or
    IS_TEXT_UNICODE_NOT_UNICODE_MASK or
    IS_TEXT_UNICODE_NOT_ASCII_MASK;
  IsTextUnicode(Pointer(Buffer), Length(Buffer), @Mask);

  // UTF-16
  if (Len mod 2 = 0) and
     (Mask and IS_TEXT_UNICODE_UNICODE_MASK <> 0) then
    Result := TEncoding.Unicode
  else
  // UTF-16 (big endian)
  if (Len mod 2 = 0) and
     (Mask and IS_TEXT_UNICODE_REVERSE_MASK <> 0) then
    Result := TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode
  else
    Result := TEncoding.ANSI;
end;
```

Если же мы хотим поведение "как в Internet Explorer", то используем такой код:

```
type
  tagDetectEncodingInfo = packed record
    nLangID: SYSUINT;
    nCodePage: SYSUINT;
    nDocPercent: SYSINT;
    nConfidence: SYSINT;
  end;

  IMultiLanguage2 = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{DCCFC164-2B38-11D2-B7EC-00C04F8F5D9A}']
    function GetNumberOfCodePageInfo(out pcCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCodePageInfo(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; LangId: Word; out pCodePageInfo: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetFamilyCodePage(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; out puiFamilyCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumCodePages(grfFlags: Cardinal; LangId: Word; out ppEnumCodePage: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCharsetInfo(const Charset: WideString; out pCharsetInfo: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function IsConvertible(dwSrcEncoding: Cardinal; dwDstEncoding: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertString(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwSrcEncoding: Cardinal; dwDstEncoding: Cardinal; var pSrcStr: Byte; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Byte; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringToUnicode(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwEncoding: Cardinal; pSrcStr: PAnsiChar; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; pDstStr: PWideChar; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringFromUnicode(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwEncoding: Cardinal; pSrcStr: PWideChar; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; pDstStr: PAnsiChar; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringReset: HResult; stdcall;
    function GetRfc1766FromLcid(locale: Cardinal; out pbstrRfc1766: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetLcidFromRfc1766(out plocale: Cardinal; const bstrRfc1766: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumRfc1766(LangId: Word; out ppEnumRfc1766: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetRfc1766Info(locale: Cardinal; LangId: Word; out pRfc1766Info: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function CreateConvertCharset(uiSrcCodePage: SYSUINT; uiDstCodePage: SYSUINT; dwProperty: Cardinal; out ppMLangConvertCharset: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringInIStream(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwFlag: Cardinal; var lpFallBack: Word; dwSrcEncoding: Cardinal; dwDstEncoding: Cardinal; const pstmIn: ISequentialStream; const pstmOut: ISequentialStream): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringToUnicodeEx(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwEncoding: Cardinal; pSrcStr: PAnsiChar; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; pDstStr: PWideChar; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT; dwFlag: Cardinal; var lpFallBack: Word): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringFromUnicodeEx(var pdwMode: Cardinal; dwEncoding: Cardinal; pSrcStr: PWideChar; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; pDstStr: PAnsiChar; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT; dwFlag: Cardinal; var lpFallBack: Word): HResult; stdcall;
    function DetectCodepageInIStream(dwFlag: Cardinal; dwPrefWinCodePage: Cardinal; const pstmIn: ISequentialStream; var lpEncoding: tagDetectEncodingInfo; var pnScores: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function DetectInputCodepage(dwFlag: Cardinal; dwPrefWinCodePage: Cardinal; pSrcStr: PAnsiChar; var pcSrcSize: SYSINT; var lpEncoding: tagDetectEncodingInfo; var pnScores: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ValidateCodePage(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; hwnd: HWND): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCodePageDescription(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; lcid: Cardinal; lpWideCharStr: PWideChar; cchWideChar: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function IsCodePageInstallable(uiCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetMimeDBSource(dwSource: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetNumberOfScripts(out pnScripts: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumScripts(dwFlags: Cardinal; LangId: Word; out ppEnumScript: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function ValidateCodePageEx(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; hwnd: HWND; dwfIODControl: Cardinal): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TSequentialStreamAdapter = class(TStreamAdapter, IStream, ISequentialStream);

function DetectEncoding(const AFileName: String): TEncoding;

  function DetectEncodingInternal(const AFileName: String): TEncoding;
  const
    CLSID_CMultiLanguage: TGUID = '{275C23E2-3747-11D0-9FEA-00AA003F8646}';
    MLDETECTCP_NONE = 0;
    MaxEncodings = 10;

  var
    Stream: ISequentialStream; // uses Winapi.ActiveX
    MLang: IMultiLanguage2;
    Encodings: array of tagDetectEncodingInfo;
    Encoding: tagDetectEncodingInfo;
    Count: Integer;
    X: Integer;
    HR: HRESULT;
  begin
    // Получаем интерфейс MLang
    Result := nil;
    try
      MLang := CreateComObject(CLSID_CMultiLanguage) as IMultiLanguage2; // uses System.Win.ComObj
    except
      on EOleSysError do
        Result := TEncoding.Default;
    end;
    if Result <> nil then
      Exit;

    // Определяем кодировку файла
    Stream := TSequentialStreamAdapter.Create(TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone), soOwned);
    Count := MaxEncodings;
    SetLength(Encodings, Count);
    FillChar(Encodings[0], Count * SizeOf(Encodings[0]), 0);
    HR := MLang.DetectCodepageInIStream(MLDETECTCP_NONE, 0, Stream, Encodings[0], Count);
    if Failed(HR) or (Count <= 0) then
    begin
      Result := TEncoding.Default;
      Exit;
    end;

    // Выбираем самый вероятный вариант
    Encoding := Encodings[0];
    for X := 1 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Encodings[X].nConfidence > Encoding.nConfidence then
        Encoding := Encodings[X]
      else
      if Encodings[X].nConfidence = Encoding.nConfidence then
        if Encodings[X].nDocPercent > Encoding.nDocPercent then
          Encoding := Encodings[X];
    end;

    Result := TEncoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.nCodePage);
  end;

var
  HR: HRESULT;
begin
  HR := CoInitializeEx(nil, 0);
  if (HR = RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE) or (not Succeeded(HR)) then
    Result := DetectEncodingInternal(AFileName)
  else
  try
    Result := DetectEncodingInternal(AFileName);
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```